# How to separate html data into a table with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to data scrape the main fundamentals table in [finviz](https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL) using

```
Public Sub TestRequest()
Dim Html As HTMLDocument, htable As HTMLTable
Set Html = New HTMLDocument
  
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL", False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Sheets("Temp").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Temp").Cells(1, 1) = Html.getElementsByClassName("snapshot-table2")(0).innerText
```

However, the entire table data gets dumped into a single cell in Excel. How do I turn the data into a neat table?

Answer (score 1):

The following code first transfers the data to your worksheet, and then creates a table...

```
Public Sub TestRequest()

    Sheets("Temp").Cells.ClearContents
    
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
      
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim htable As HTMLTable
    Set htable = Html.getElementsByClassName("snapshot-table2")(0)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    With htable
        For r = 0 To .Rows.Length - 1
            For c = 0 To .Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1
                Sheets("Temp").Cells(r + 1, c + 1).Value = .Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
    End With
    
    Sheets("Temp").ListObjects.Add _
        SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
        Source:=Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
        xllistobjecthasheaders:=xlNo
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!